# Fetch API data using Stream builder flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data from API and I am using Stream builder but I am unable to fetch data from API. Following are my code:

I initalize stream controller

```
final StreamController<APIModel> _streamController = StreamController();
```

Method for get data from API

```
Future<APIModel> getdatafromAPI() async {
    var url =
        "myapi";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //sink data for stream builder
      _streamController.sink.add(APIModel.fromJson(data));
      return MayyatNewsModel.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      return MayyatNewsModel.fromJson(data);
    }
  }
```

in response == 200 i used stream controller to sink all response data into the controller.

Following are ui part to show data but unable to load this data. What is the problem?? or what is the right way to use Streambuilder??

```
...
StreamBuilder<APIModel>(
                      stream: _streamController.stream,
                      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<MayyatNewsModel> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return ListView.builder(
...
```

Comment: where do you call `getdatafromAPI()`?

Comment: Yes, I was think it calls in stream builder when i calles stream controller.  Now where write this method for call?

Comment: @TakiRajani how do you plan to call `getdatafromAPI`?

Comment: no, you have to call it, btw do you want to call your API only once or maybe every, say 5 minutes or something?

Comment: I am creating one project like blog app, when ever user add any blog at same time i have show data in list. I want to do real time data fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your `getdatafromAPI` for every specific duration you need to first define new stream variable like this:

```
late Stream<APIModel> stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5))
  .asyncMap((event) async => await getdatafromAPI());
```

then use it like this:

```
StreamBuilder<APIModel>(
    stream: stream,
    builder: ...
),
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I was accept your answer same day but any how green tick is disselect. By the way I again accept this answer. thank you once again